# wxpython: how to call function after EVT_DATAVIEW_COLUMN_SORTED event completely finishes?

Tags: python, sorting, events, wxpython

[Python v3.7.9 x64; wxPython v4.1.0; MS Windows 10 x64]

I'm using a wx.dataview.DataViewListCtrl widget, and I enabled sorting on one of the columns in the list control with:

```
first_col = self.dv_list_control.Columns[0]  # gets first col of the DataViewListCtrl
first_col.SetSortable(sortable=True)  # allows sorting of first col
```

This works great, when the header of the first column is selected, all of the data in the list control is sorted as you would expect.

I need to detect when the data is sorted because after the data gets sorted, I need to immediately retrieve all the data stored in the list control and process it.

Currently, I have simple function that is bound to the `dataview.EVT_DATAVIEW_COLUMN_SORTED` event. Though, the list control does not update and sort the data until after the function is returned - it is apparent the event has not yet completed.

I've tried using `Update()`, `UpdateWindowUI()`, `Refresh()`, `CallAfter()`, `Yield()`, `SafeYield()`, and more. I'm not an expert with wxpython, and I've exhausted what I can think of doing. I'm not sure if it possible to "detect when event has completely finished processing and do something" or if there is some other means of executing a function immediately after an event has finished?? This seems something that would be common in certain situations like this one.

Some example code, links, or anything would be helpful - thanks.

=====**Edit**=====
So I messed around some more and my previous question may not be the only issue. After sorting by clicking the column header, and then retrieving the data in the list control, the data retrieved is no longer sorted but instead is in it's original order. I suppose the sorting must be performed on some unique id associated with each row of data in the list control.

Is there a way to retrieve the data exactly in the order it appears after it has been sorted?

Comment: I just answered my edit question. Doing `first_col.SetReorderable(reorderable=True)` reorders the data in the list control after it was sorted.

Comment: It seems like `SetReoderable()` does not do what I previously said... will sit tight for someone more experience to come along.